# SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio TRANSFORM ROW-COL NOT USING PIVOT (AGGREGATE) CAN IT BE DONE?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transform, rows

I don't want to create an aggregate function (`sum, count, max`). `PIVOT` requires that.

My issue is that someone long before I was born probably "read" data in as two columns that really should have been column data with 1 value per column, multiplied by 'n' records.

Their dataset:

```
(RECORDSET, NAME, VALUE)
(1, FIELD1, char1-1)
(1, FIELD2, char2-1)
(1, FIELD3, int3-1)
(1, FIELD4, char4-1)
(…)
(…)
(…)
(1, FIELD26, float26-1)
(2, FIELD1, char1-2)
(2, FIELD2, char2-2)
(2, FIELD3, int3-2)
(2, FIELD4, char4-2)
(…)
(…)
(…)
(2, FIELD26, float26-2)
(3, FIELD1, char1-3)
(3, FIELD2, char2-3)
(3, FIELD3, int3-3)
(3, FIELD4, char4-3)
(…)
(…)
(…)
(3, FIELD26, float26-3)
```

I need each set of 26 records to be like this:

```
FIELD1......FIELD2......FIELD3......FIELD4.............FIELD 26
char1-1.....char2-1.....int3-1......char4-1............float26-1
char1-2.....char2-2.....int3-2......char4-2............float26-2
char1-3.....char2-3.....int3-3......char4-3............float26-3
```

and so on.

Comment: You could use pivot with max() over values because max(x) equals x if there is only one matching row - and in your case there is. (RECORDSET, NAME) seem unique to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?ppud=4) so I included a pivot version and some other options as well.

A version with pivot and an aggregate. [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70965)

```
select P.FIELD1, P.FIELD2, P.FIELD3, P.FIELD4
from YourTable T
pivot (min(T.VALUE) for T.NAME in (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4)) P
```

A version without pivot but still using an aggregate. [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70967)

```
select min(case when T.NAME = 'FIELD1' then T.VALUE end) as FIELD1,
       min(case when T.NAME = 'FIELD2' then T.VALUE end) as FIELD2,
       min(case when T.NAME = 'FIELD3' then T.VALUE end) as FIELD3,
       min(case when T.NAME = 'FIELD4' then T.VALUE end) as FIELD4
from (select RECORDSET, NAME, VALUE from YourTable) T
group by T.RECORDSET
```

No pivot and no aggregate. [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70968)

```
select T.R.value('(VALUE[@Name = "FIELD1"])[1]', 'varchar(10)') as FIELD1,
       T.R.value('(VALUE[@Name = "FIELD2"])[1]', 'varchar(10)') as FIELD2,
       T.R.value('(VALUE[@Name = "FIELD3"])[1]', 'varchar(10)') as FIELD3,
       T.R.value('(VALUE[@Name = "FIELD4"])[1]', 'varchar(10)') as FIELD4
from
    (
      select (select T1.NAME as "@Name",
                     T1.VALUE as "*"
              from @T T1
              where T1.RECORDSET = T.RECORDSET
              for xml path('VALUE'), root('RECORDSET'), type)
      from YourTable T
      group by T.RECORDSET
      for xml path(''), type
    ) X(XML)
  cross apply X.XML.nodes('RECORDSET') as T(R)
```

Another no pivot no aggregate version. [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70969)

```
select (select T2.VALUE
        from YourTable T2
        where T.RECORDSET = T2.RECORDSET and
              T2.NAME = 'FIELD1') as FIELD1,
       (select T2.VALUE
        from YourTable T2
        where T.RECORDSET = T2.RECORDSET and
              T2.NAME = 'FIELD2') as FIELD2,
       (select T2.VALUE
        from YourTable T2
        where T.RECORDSET = T2.RECORDSET and
             T2.NAME = 'FIELD3') as FIELD3,
       (select T2.VALUE
        from YourTable T2
        where T.RECORDSET = T2.RECORDSET and
             T2.NAME = 'FIELD4') as FIELD4
from YourTable T
group by T.RECORDSET
```

Comment: Well, it appears that you've provided the fundamental transform, very excited. Now I have to apply it against the 'real' world (ah ah) ... will let you know tonight or tomorrow. =o),

Comment: Please read above under "Another no pivot no aggregate version. SE-Data" ------- denotes where my text starts.

Comment: You should really use the`pivot` version. As you can see the result is the same but performance is much better, at lest much better than the last two and a bit better than the second version. To make this work for you you need to replace `YourTable` with whatever your table is called.